# Why use SomeType[1] instead of SomeType* as last member in structs

Tags: c++

I saw in the code next statement:

```
SomeType someVar[1];
```

Later `someVar` is used as a pointer to `SomeType`. Why would one declare it like this instead of:

```
SomeType* someVar;
```

EDIT: As many pointed out, I need to specify the context.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    size_t count;
    SomeType someVar[1];
};

SomeStruct* str = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct) + sizeof(SomeType) * count);
str->count = count
...
```

`str->someVar` is used as an array with `count` elements of `SomeType` from this point.

Comment: The second one uses pointers concept.

Comment: It would help to have the whole context.  For instance if it is the last item in a struct declaration then it's possible the intent is to allocate more memory than the struct needs and use the extra as more space for the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SomeType someVar[1];
```

`someVar` is an array of type `SomeType` with 1 element.

```
SomeType* someVar;
```

`someVar` is a *pointer* (dangling still, you didn't point it to anything yet) of type `SomeType`.

> And you can use the name of an array on its own as a shorthand for a pointer to the first element of that array.

[Will Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987/will-dean)

Comment: And you can use the name of an array on its own as a shorthand for a pointer to the first element of that array.

Answer (score 1):

Because generically speaking they are not the same. The first one defines one element array of SomeType and the other defines pointer to SomeType.

The first allocates memory for that one element, the other does not.

In general: `sizeof(SOmeType[1]) != sizeof(SomeType*).`

Answer (score 0):

The first can be treated as a pointer to a possibly uninitialized `SomeType` (initialized if it's a non-POD type). The second is just a dangling pointer.

```
 SomeType someVar[1];
 someVar[0]; //valid
 *someVar;   //valid
```

vs

```
 SomeType* someVar;
 someVar[0]; //invalid
 *someVar;   //invalid
```

For the second one to work, you'd need to make it point to something valid, so either an existing object (so then there's no point in having the pointer there), or to a new object allocated with `new`, in which case there's the downside that you have to call `delete` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SomeType*, you will need a `new` at some point and you will thus have to `delete` it to avoid leaks.

Using SomeType[] allocates on the stack and the memory management will be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `SomeType someVar[1];` allocates memory on the stack and it gives you a block/function scoped variable. So it will be automatically destroyed when it is out of the block/function.
2. `SomeType* someVar;` is a pointer (to nothing meaningful yet), so it doesn't allocate any for `SomeType`. However if you have something like this:

`SomeType* someVar = malloc(sizeof(SomeType));`

of equivalent:

`SomeType* someVar = new SomeType(...);`

Then that is memory allocation on the heap. So it is not destroyed when out of scope and it needs to be destroyed manually by `free` or `delete`.